# Short code and notation in python

Tags: python

I see some codes like this:

```
K = np.array([B[z==i].mean(axis=0) for i in range(k)])
```

Where `B` is a 2D array (matrix) and `z` is a 1D array (vector).

I am wondering what `B[z==i]` means?

Comment: It's indexing `B` with the result of `z==I`.

Comment: but `z==i` will return boolean value

Comment: but z is a 1d array, how can `z == i ` ?

Comment: it would more helpful to provide more code context.

Answer (score 0):

In `B[z==i]` you have two types of operations.

First, given `B[i] for i in range(k)` what are you doing in cases like this is an iteration over the values of the list **B**.

In your case you have `z==i` which is a comparison between **objects**.
In python the objects to compare does not need to have the same type, but if the types are different, they always return `False`.

A little summary of how comparisons work:

> Numbers are compared arithmetically.
>
> Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents
>   (the result of the built-in function ord()) of their characters.
>   Unicode and 8-bit strings are fully interoperable in this behavior.
>
> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of
>   corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element
>   must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and
>   have the same length.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first
>   differing elements. For example, cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y]) returns the
>   same as cmp(x,y). If the corresponding element does not exist, the
>   shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3]).
>
> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted
>   (key, value) lists compare equal.5.3Outcomes other than equality are
>   resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined.
>
> Most other types compare unequal unless they are the same object; the
>   choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another
>   one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one execution of a
>   program.

This document is a little bit old but you can have more information about comparisons there: [source](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/comparisons.html)